# How to mapping values?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to get specific information of an object is returned, how can I do this is achieved if there is the following:
I have javascript-code

```
        var data = {
        Id: null,
        Name_Product: null,
        Price: null,
        Description: null
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/editpr',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: tested }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            var Price = data.Price
            var newinput = document.createElement('input')
            newinput.className = 'save_inp'
            newinput.id = 'id_save_inp'
            newinput.value = Price
            $('.price').html(newinput)
```

and it's must return values from mvc controller:

```
  public Products Editproducts([FromBody] int id)
    {       
      //  Products Product = null;
        DBEntities bd = new DBEntities();
        Products SenMes = bd.Products.Find(id);
        if (SenMes != null)
        {
            Products product = new Products
            {
                Id = SenMes.Id,
               Name_Product = SenMes.Name_Product,
                Description = SenMes.Description,
                Price = SenMes.Price,
                MesAndProduct = SenMes.MesAndProduct
            };
          // Product = SenMes;
            return product;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But i have bad result [image]

Answer (score 0):

When you do it that way the controller receives an object with a property named `id`, not just the integer.

One method would be to accept a custom Type (actually any serializable type that has an int property named `id` would work).

```
class IntHolder
{
    public int id {get;set;}
}

public Products Editproducts([FromBody] IntHolder holder)
    {       
      //  Products Product = null;
        DBEntities bd = new DBEntities();
        Products SenMes = bd.Products.Find(holder.id);
        if (SenMes != null)
        {
            Products product = new Products
            {
                Id = SenMes.Id,
               Name_Product = SenMes.Name_Product,
                Description = SenMes.Description,
                Price = SenMes.Price,
                MesAndProduct = SenMes.MesAndProduct
            };
          // Product = SenMes;
            return product;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I need to get the object "price", but it is comes "undefined". How i can get Price?

Comment: So if `bd.Products.Find()` returns a `Products` then the `SenMes` property values are not related to your initial question.

Comment: I need to learn how i can get the item from the object in JavaScript

Comment: Well, make sure it is set in the controller before the response is sent. Debug your controller, does `SenMes.Price` have a value?

Comment: Yes, it's have value
http://prntscr.com/dmsxwr   - SenMes
http://prntscr.com/dmsy1m - Price 
It's values of my selected id

Comment: I'm not going to click those links, what are you trying to show? Consider editing your question.